# Need a word for someone that makes requests of others, but doesn't do that for the other person

Tags: single-word-requests

Like, your husband asks you to be quiet when you come in late, then is loud when he comes in late.  Or not to talk across rooms, but is constantly yelling from other rooms himself?  Sentence I would use it in:  I wish that you would follow your own rules, as I find your behavior very XXXXX and not fair.

Comment: Make that Quiet ( not quite) in the example

Comment: [Inconsiderate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconsiderate) or [discourteous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discourteous) might work.

Comment: While I totally agree, was looking for something along the lines of hypocrite, but that isn't quite right?  Duplicitous was what I was thinking, but after looking that up it isn't right either...

Comment: If you mean *lacking a sense of moral responsibility or social conscious,* try [sociopath](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sociopath).

Comment: The other question is "do the opposite" and the OP description seems to fit that.  If however a person thought they were above such rules, you might try a word like "autocrat" *1.1 An imperious person who insists on complete obedience from others.
‘Eva was an autocrat—people didn't argue unless they had a lot of courage’* https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autocrat   I don't think it is hypocritical for parents to expect different behavior from kids than they do themselves. With power comes privilege.

Answer (score 0):

hypocrite:

one who does not act according to how they expect others to act.

Comment: can you cite where you got your definition from

Comment: hypocritical is the proper form of hypocrite that would fit in OPs example